# Is it correct to use a paired t-test for this question?

Tags: self-study, t-test, paired-data

this is an exam practice question for my 1st year stats class and I just want to see if I have approached this problem correctly and to clarify my understanding.

Here is the complete question:

A professor is deciding whether to schedule an end of semester Stats exam in the morning (9am) or in the afternoon (2pm). He's not sure if attention levels are lower or higher in the afternoon than in the morning.

To test this he selects a group of 20 students and exposed them to a psych task. In this task lights randomly ash over a period of 20 minutes and the subject is required to press a button within a certain time of a light ashing.

Failure to react to a flashing light is called a `lapse'. The more lapses the poorer the attention of the student. The students were given the task at 9am (AM) and again at 2pm (PM) and the number of lapses for each student is recorded in R as follows:

```
AM = c(1,5,4,2,6,6, 7, 11,5,3,4,5,8,3,4,5,7,7,4,5)    
PM = c(4,5,5,8,9,10,12,15,4,8,6,6,9,5,9,8,7,8,7,6)
```

(a) State an appropriate null and alternative hypothesis, stating any parameters used.

(b) State an appropriate test statistic to test this hypothesis and the null distribution of this test statistic, stating and checking any assumptions required.

(c) Calculate the test statistic chosen in (b), the corresponding p-value and form an appropriate conclusion.

(d) Calculate an appropriate confidence interval and provide a formal interpretation.

---

**Here is my answer to this question:**

(a)

My null hypothesis is that there is no difference in the average number of lapses for morning and afternoon. I.e.

$H_{0}: U_{d} = 0 $

The alternative hypothesis is that the difference is greater than 0. i.e.

$H_{1}: U_{d} > 0 $

The parameter of interest is the population mean difference (actually I don't completely understand what the question is asking here - when it says state any parameters used?)

(b)

My assumption is that the differences are independent and identically distributed normal random variables. i.e.:

$D_{i} \sim \mathcal{N}(U_{d}, \sigma^2),\mathrm{iid}  $

Upon checking the distribution in R - it does appear normal.

The test statistic used is:

$ t = \frac{\bar{D}-U_{d}}{S_{d}\sqrt(n)}  $

Where $n$ is the number of pairs, $\bar{D}$ is the mean of the sample differences, $S_{d}$ the standard deviation of the differences, and $U_{d}$ is the mean of the population differences.

Also assumed is that the null distribution of the test statistic is normal.

(c)

Calculating the data in R, I have $\bar{D} = -2.45$, $S_{d} = 1.959$, $n=20$.

Therefore the observed test statistic is:

$ t_{obs} = \frac{-2.45-0}{1.959\sqrt(20)} \approx -5.5917 $

Using a 5% level of significance, the critical value is $t^* = $ `qt(0.95,19)` $\approx 1.729133$

Since $ -5.5917 < -1.729133$, we reject the null hypothesis and conclude that there is evidence to suggest that there are less lapses (better attention) in students in the AM.

(Am I correct to take the negative for the critical value here?)

The corresponding p-value is $\approx 1.079061\times 10^{-5}$ (`pt(-5.5917,19)` in R) and since this is much smaller than $0.05$ we reject the null hypothesis.

(d)

Finally, looking for a 95% confidence interval - I observe that the alternative hypothesis is one sided $(H_{1}: U_{d} > 0)$, so a one sided confidence interval is used.

The lower bound of the one sided CI is:

$\bar{D}-t^{*}\frac{S_{d}}{\sqrt{n}} = -2.45 - 1.729133\frac{1.959457}{\sqrt{20}} \approx -3.207616002$

So the 95% CI is $(-3.207616002, \infty)$ since $ -5.5917$ falls outside this interval - so I conclude that there is a significant difference in student's attention levels between AM and PM (specifically, that it is better in the AM).

Have I made any errors here in my logic here and are the calculations reasonable?

Many thanks! Just want to make sure that I am on the right track!

Comment: Some comments: (a) Looks good, although, strictly speaking, the null hypothesis would be $H_{0}: U_{d}\leq 0$, (c) the $p$-value is wrong. Because you have a one-sided hypothesis, the $p$-value is here $\mathrm{P}(t_{\mathrm{crit}}>t_{\mathrm{obs}})$ which is $\approx 1$ in this case. So you have no evidence against the null hypothesis. You can calculate a $t$-test in `R` with the command `t.test(AM,PM, paired=TRUE, alternative="greater")`.

Comment: Why would a *one-tailed* alternative be reasonable for part (a)?

Comment: @Glen_b, should the alternative hypothesis be that the difference in the means is not equal to 0?

Comment: @COOLSerdash - so if the p-value gives no evidence against the null hypothesis then does that mean my other conclusions, i.e. with the confidence interval is incorrect?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately: 1) You compare the observed $t$-value with the confidence interval. But the confidence interval is for the *mean difference* and not for the statistic (i.e. $t$-value). 2) The null hypothesis states that the mean difference is at most $0$. But the lower bound of the confidence interval is below $0$, so again, you have no evidence against the null hypothesis.

Comment: ah ok, thanks so much. So I would assume I have made an error in interpreting the critical value as well. Is it supposed to be that since $t_{obs} < t_{crit}$, (i.e. $-5.5917 < 1.72418$ ) - I have no evidence against the null hypothesis? Was I incorrect to take the negative of the critical value?

Comment: @COOLSerdash, if I input the R commands: d = PM-AM
t.test(d, mu=0, alternative="greater") - is that different from what you have done with - t.test(AM,PM, paired=TRUE, alternative="greater") ? I did both and got different values for the p-value. What would be the difference with the two?